# Resolve constructor argument with parameter from base class

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, castle-windsor

I have a custom ASP.NET MVC controller that retrieves operations from the user service. I want to pass the operations property to the scenario service using dependency injection.

```
public abstract class BaseController : Controller {
    protected IUserService userService;
    public OperationWrapper operations { get; private set; }
    public BaseController(IUserService userService) {
        this.userService = userService;
        this.operations = userService.GetOperations(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name);
    }
}

public abstract class ScenarioController : BaseController {
    protected IScenarioService scenarioService;
    public ScenarioController(IScenarioService scenarioService, IUserService userService)
        : base(userService) {
        this.scenarioService = scenarioService;
    }
}

public class ScenarioService : IScenarioService {
    private OperationWrapper operations;
    public ScenarioService(OperationWrapper operations) {
        this.repo = repo;
        this.operations = operations;
    }
}
```

Here is my Windsor installer.

```
public class Installer : IWindsorInstaller {
    public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store) {
        container.Register(Classes.FromThisAssembly()
                        .BasedOn<IController>());

        container.Register(Classes.FromThisAssembly()
                            .Where(x => x.Name.EndsWith("Service"))
                            .WithService.DefaultInterfaces()
                            .LifestyleTransient());
    }
}
```

I pretty sure I've done something similar with Ninject a couple of years back. What do I need to add to the installer in order to make this work? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few of options here:

#### 1. Use `LifeStylePerWebRequest()` and `UsingFactoryMethod()`

First, you could register an `OperationWrapper` as [`LifestylePerWebRequest()`](https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/master/docs/mvc-tutorial-part-7-lifestyles.md) and inject it into both the `BaseController` and `ScenarioService`. Windsor will let you register the dependency with a factory method for creating it, which can in turn call other services which have been registered.

```
container.Register(Component.For<OperationWrapper>()
                            .LifestylePerWebRequest()
                            .UsingFactoryMethod(kernel =>
                            {
                               var userService = kernel.Resolve<IUserService>();
                               try
                               {
                                  return userService.GetOperations(
                                               HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name);
                               }
                               finally
                               {
                                  kernel.ReleaseComponent(userService);
                               }
                            }));
```

So, every time Windsor is asked for an `OperationWrapper`, it will run that call against an instance if `IUserService`, giving it the `Name` of the current `User`. By binding the lifestyle to `LifestylePerWebRequest()`, you can verify that each request will get its own instance of the `OperationWrapper` and it won't bleed across requests.

*(The only edge case you'd run into is one where a user becomes authenticated mid-request and the `OperationWrapper` needs to be adjusted as a result. If that's a normal-path use case, this may need some re-thinking.)*

Then, modify your base controller to take that registered object in as a dependency:

```
public abstract class BaseController : Controller {
    protected IUserService userService;
    protected OperationWrapper operations;
    public BaseController(IUserService userService, OperationWrapper operations) {
        this.userService = userService;
        this.operations = operations;
    }
}
```

#### 2. Use Method Injection

It looks like `OperationWrapper` is some sort of context object, and those can sometimes be injected into the method instead of into the constructor.

For instance, if your method was:

```
int GetTransactionId() { /* use OperationWrapper property */ }
```

You could just modify the signature to look like:

```
int GetTransactionId(OperationWrapper operations) { /* use arg */ }
```

In this situation, it makes sense to use it if a small-ish subset of your service's methods use that dependency. If the majority (or totality) of methods need it, then you should probably go a different route.

#### 3. Don't use DI for `OperationWrapper` at all

In situations where you have a highly-stateful contextual object (which it seems like your `OperationWrapper` is), it frequently just makes sense to have a property whose value gets passed around. Since the object is based on some current thread state and is accessible from everywhere in any subclassed `Controller`, it may be *right* to just keep the pattern you have.

If you can't answer the question "What am I unable to do with `OperationWrapper` now that DI is going to solve for me?" with anything but "use the pattern/container," this may be the option for this particular situation.

Answer (score 0):

You should set dependency resolver in Application_Start method of global.asax

```
System.Web.MVC.DependencyResolver.SetResolver(your windsor resolver)
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a class that inherits from `DefaultControllerFactory`. Something like this will do:

```
public class WindsorControllerFactory : DefaultControllerFactory
{
    public WindsorControllerFactory(IKernel kernel)
    {
        _kernel = kernel;
    }

    protected override IController GetControllerInstance(RequestContext requestContext, Type controllerType)
    {
        if (controllerType == null)
        {
            throw new HttpException(
                404,
                String.Format(
                    CultureInfo.CurrentCulture,
                    "The controller for path '{0}' was not found or does not implement IController.",
                    requestContext.HttpContext.Request.Path
                    )
                );
        }

        return (IController)_kernel.Resolve(controllerType);    
    }

    public override void ReleaseController(IController controller)
    {
        Kernel.ReleaseComponent(controller);
    }

    private readonly IKernel _kernel;

    private IKernel Kernel
    {
        get { return _kernel; }
    }
}
```

In the `Application_Start` method of your `MvcApplication` class add the following:

```
var container = new WindsorContainer();

container.Install(FromAssembly.This());

ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(
    new WindsorControllerFactory(container.Kernel)
);
```

This should work with your existing installer and get you to the point where Windsor will start resolving your dependencies for you. You might have to fill-in a few gaps, but you'll get the point.

I've borrowed heavily from: https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/master/docs/mvc-tutorial-intro.md

Be wary of using IDependencyResolver as it doesn't make provision for releasing what's resolved.

Comment: I have all ready registered the controller factory, so that's not the problem. In the ScenarioController constructor I used to have scenarioService = new ScenarioService(operations), now I want to resolve it with dependency injection but I can't figure out how to pass the operations property from the BaseController to the ScenarioService with dependency injection.